# How do I access the init.el file on emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am extremely inexperienced with all this Unix stuff and recently downloaded Emacs, but when I tried to run my python program this showed up:

> Warning (python): Your `python-shell-interpreter` doesn’t seem to support `readline`, yet `python-shell-completion-native-enable` was `t` and `"python"` is not part of the `python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters` list.  Native completions have been disabled locally.

There are fixes out there, one of which includes adding to the `init.el` file, but I'm not entirely sure how I would go about doing that or how to exactly access that. The other solution is a Github download, but I'm also not sure on how to incorporate that into my Emacs.

I'm super inexperienced, and answers to both potential solutions would highly be appreciated as I want to learn as much as possible.

Comment: `init.el` refers to the per-user file that Emacs reads on startup. It can be either `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` - Emacs picks the first one of those that it finds. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27869909/113848), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189490/113848) if you're running Emacs under Windows.

Comment: As for Github downloads, you'll find that many of those are present in [MELPA](https://melpa.org/), the largest Emacs package archive. Follow the "Getting started" instructions, and then try `M-x list-packages` and see if you can find the package you need there. That can be less fiddly than downloading things manually.